# Getting a Pandas dataframe from an Apache log file

Tags: python, apache, pandas, optimization

I have a log file that has 1,770,781 lines of the form

```
[02/Jan/2015:08:08:43] "GET /click?article_id=139&user_id=19550 HTTP/1.1" 200 3078
```

and I want to extract the time, article_id, and user_id, and combine these in a convenient format for analysis.  Right now, I have the following code that extracts these elements and attempts to combine them in a Pandas DataFrame:

```
logs = pd.DataFrame(columns=['time', 'article_id', 'user_id'])
regex = '\[(?P<time>.*?)\] "GET (.*?=)(?P<article_id>\d+)(&.*?=)(?P<user_id>\d+)'

for line in log_file:
    time = re.match(regex, line).group('time')
    article_id = re.match(regex, line).group('article_id')
    user_id = re.match(regex, line).group('user_id')
    logs.append([time, article_id, user_id])
```

But this takes forever to run, and I'm starting to think I should abandon this approach.  Is there any way to make this more efficient?  Is it even realistic to be trying to do this?  If not, is there a better way to get at these data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were not using `re.compile` and you were also matching inefficiently three times when one time would have been enough inside the loop.

```
logs = pd.DataFrame(columns=['time', 'article_id', 'user_id'])
# regc = re.compile(r'\[(?P<time>.*?)\] "GET (.*?=)(?P<article_id>\d+)(&.*?=)(?P<user_id>\d+)')
# alternative regexp that might be more efficient
regc = re.compile(r'\[(?P<time>.+)\] "GET (?:.+article_id=)(?P<article_id>\d+)(?:&user_id=)(?P<user_id>\d+)')

for line in log_file:
    m = regc.match(line)
    time = m.group('time')
    article_id = m.group('article_id')
    user_id = m.group('user_id')
    logs.append([time, article_id, user_id])
```

Comment: In the fourth line, do you mean `m=re.match(regc, line)`?

Comment: @dmdmdmdmdmd That `regex` should not have been there, I edited my answer.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much for your response.  I am estimating that this will take about 60 minutes to run.  Is there perhaps a better way to do this?

Comment: @dmdmdmdmdmd I don't have much experience with pandas. Could you rule out slowdown because of it, i.e. first `logs = []` and then in loop `logs.append((time, article_id, user_id))`?